# What does "this" refer to in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, antecedents

If it refers to ***our progress in understanding***, what is the difference between ***our progress in understanding*** and ***the progress of knowledge***?

> He was disappointed that scientific progress has not cured the
> world’s ills by abolishing wars and starvation; that gross human
> inequality is still widespread; that happiness is not universal. My
> friend made a common mistake — a basic misunderstanding in the nature
> of knowledge. Knowledge is amoral — not immoral but morality neutral.
> It can be used for any purpose, but many people assume it will be used
> to further their favorite hopes for society — and this is the
> fundamental flaw. Knowledge of the world is one thing; its uses create
> a separate issue. To be disappointed that our progress in
> understanding has not remedied the social ills of the world is a
> legitimate view, but to confuse ***this*** with the progress of
> knowledge is absurd. To argue that knowledge is not progressing
> because of the African or Middle Eastern conflicts misses the point.
> There is nothing inherent in knowledge that dictates any specific
> social or moral application.

[The Knowledge Drive: Confronting Mythological Beliefs](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=dpGFUWpmcPwC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=To%20be%20disappointed%20that%20our%20progress%20in%20understanding%20has%20not%20remedied%20the%20social%20ills%20of%20the%20world%20is%20a%20legitimate%20view,&source=bl&ots=b8waq6pDfP&sig=ACfU3U26Hl2Hpee_1CoNnTOIWV-g_k6ujg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje3e68j_brAhWKGqYKHYykDMgQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=To%20be%20disappointed%20that%20our%20progress%20in%20understanding%20has%20not%20remedied%20the%20social%20ills%20of%20the%20world%20is%20a%20legitimate%20view%2C&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

No, I believe that *this* refers to the fact that the social ills of the world have not been remedied (the thing that they are disappointed about)

I agree that it is not clearly expressed.